# How do I pass/catch/respond to Python's KeyboardInterrupt in C++?

Tags: c++, python, interrupt, boost-python

I have a simple library written in C++ which I'm creating a Python wrapper for using boost.python. Some functions take a long time to execute (over 30 seconds), and I would like to make it interruptible so that when I hit ctrl-d to trigger KeyboardInterrupt in the python interpreter, I'm somehow able to respond to that in C++.

Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find any information about interrupts and boost.python at boost.org or python.org.

Comment: If you have a minimal working example of this, it would be most helpful if you would include it. Thanks.

Comment: I found an example [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2010-February/015209.html), but it is complicated. As it happens it uses PyErr_CheckSignals().

Comment: The answer below, using PyErr_CheckSignals() works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`PyErr_CheckSignals()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/exceptions.html#PyErr_CheckSignals) every so often.

Comment: A minimal complete working example would be most helpful here.